# Accesslog functionality?

Tags: 8

Accesslog was removed from the Statistics module in Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/node/1446956. Does this functionality now exist somewhere else in core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in [Accesslog removed from the Statistics module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900384), the module with that functionality is the [Better Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics) module, which (at the moment I am writing this answer) doesn't have a Drupal 8 version.

> The accesslog and all associated reports have been removed from the core Statistics module. This functionality exists in contrib at http://drupal.org/project/better_statistics.

There is a issue open for porting the module to Drupal 8, [Port Better Statistics to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2047335), which was created after the change record.

The History module in Drupal core doesn't keep a log for the access to all the pages, but it keeps a log for the access to nodes. If you are interesting just to the users who accessed a node, that could help you.

Comment: It's what I said.

Comment: It means the change record is pointing to a module that doesn't have, so far, a Drupal 8 version. If the OP finds the History module useful, he could look at that, since the question asked about core.

Comment: I'll look into the History module. It may be what I need. Thanks.

Comment: No, the History module does not help me. I need to know data about visitors and referrers to nodes. It should not be too hard to rebuild some of this lost functionality though.